# Using ArrayFormula for a running total causes a circular reference

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, sumifs, cumulative-sum

See attached Google Sheet for example/sample of my issue.  I am trying to use an `ARRAYFORMULA()` to keep a running total in column C, based on adding the previous row's value in column C with the current row's value in column B.  Before I make it an `ARRAYFORMULA`, it works fine. In column F-H, you can see I tried the array version and get a "circular dependency" error.

The working formula:
`=B3+C2`   (this is in cell C3)

The non-working formula (with the desired `ARRAYFORMULA`):
`=ArrayFormula(G3:G+H2:H)` (this is in cell H3)

My question is, what adjustments can I make to my formula that will allow me to auto-fill this formula down the page as new rows are added (and not populating data for blanks).

```
Name    Days    Total Days
Jane    5       6
Tom     2       8
Billy   4       12
Sue     6       18
Sally   1       19
```

[Sample document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mkfom-OaiqLiHU3y_5plFkx3GkM56LC4535i08wl5lU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="", ,SUMIF(ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B), B2:B)+1))
```

[image: 0]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AR00jDAgv5KphDQIyF-4i9CWZBQTkg6JTv4IMM9Ppk4/edit#gid=0&range=C2)

Answer (score 0):

if this is what you need ( to always sum total in C column ),

[image]

then you don't need arrayformula you can use this simple cell formula (this is C2 formula):

```
=B2+(If(ISNUMBER(C1), C1, 0))
```

and spread it down the page, [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ehcPsC7JJpZqyO8b9dvt0WaS5oWLDU3-U0ovWNFgwnI/edit?usp=sharing) is the sheet I captured

cheers, kres

Comment: Kresimir thank you for the reply.  Indeed the formula is doing the simple calculation correctly, however, my question is related to making this an arrayformula so the column calculates automatically when new rows are added.  The data in my real sheet is too dynamic to have to drag formulas down the page every time rows are added and removed.  Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Do you know if this is possible in sheets?

Comment: @TimS I think that's possible yes, but I'm not very good with `ArrayFormula`, try to post your question on Google sheets Forms to see if gurus there knows,, I could do it with Google App Scripts, but that's programing solution,,

Comment: did you find the answer @TimS